# jqzoom on multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-manipulation, zooming

I have the standard setup of one main image and multiple thumbnails which can be cliced to change the main image. I'm using jqzoom on the main image but was having the common problem of the main image changing and the zoomed image just going blank. Looking through stack overflow i found some code that claimed to correct this, and in a way it does. But rather than allow each changed image to have a zoom, it makes the main image just a link to the large version, bypassing the jqzoom function call.

to show the two examples:
with the standard jqzoom code and thumbnails not showing zooms:
http://designerspider.net/clients/jge/project2.php?id=17

with added code and images just becoming links:
http://designerspider.net/clients/jge/project.php?id=17

the code i added was

> ```
>   $(".thumbs a").click(function(){
> ```

```
      $(".jqclass").unbind();

      $(".jqclass").jqzoom(options);

      return false;
  };
```

if anyone can see if i have missed anything, or need to do it a diffferent way, i'd appreciate any and all advice. I can't understand why adding the extra function would disable the main jqzoom feature :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find, because you are using two functions side by side, one to change images, and the other to unbind the zoom function, and then rebind it, the 2nd function is finishing before the image has changed. So when the image does change, it still won't work.

Second problem, you are not actually unbinding anything.

So, try firstly changing to:

```
$(".jqclass").unbind(".jqclass");
```

Alternatively you could migrate a little more to jQuery. I have tested this:

You HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="projectphotos">
    <div id="photo_1">
        <a href="http://designerspider.net/clients/jge/projects/h07_03_11_12_10_58.jpg" class="jqclass">
            <img src="http://designerspider.net/clients/jge/projects/h07_03_11_12_10_58.jpg" class="projectimg2" alt="Mid 15th C Oakeshott Type XXa" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="photo_2" style="display:none;">
        <a href="http://designerspider.net/clients/jge/projects/h07_03_11_12_19_49.jpg">
            <img src="http://designerspider.net/clients/jge/projects/h07_03_11_12_19_49.jpg" class="projectimg2" alt="Mid 15th C Oakeshott Type XXa" />
        </a>
    </div>                                       
    <div class="thumbsdiv">
        <ul class="thumbs">
            <li>
                <img rel="photo_1" src="http://designerspider.net/clients/jge/projects/h07_03_11_12_10_58.jpg" width="80" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img rel="photo_2" src="http://designerspider.net/clients/jge/projects/h07_03_11_12_19_49.jpg" width="80" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your jQuery like this, I've explained each line:

```
var options = {
    zoomWidth: 250,
    zoomHeight: 250,
    position: 'right',
    yOffset: 0,
    xOffset: 0,
    title: false
}
$(".jqclass").jqzoom(options);

// Make the thumbnail look clickable:
$(".thumbs img").each(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
// React to clicking on a thumbnail:
$(".thumbs img").click(function() {
    // Get the photo linked to:
    var photo = $(this).attr('rel');
    // Unbind the zoom:
    $(".jqclass").unbind(".jqclass");
    // Hide the current image via its parent DIV:
    $(".jqclass").parent().hide();
    // Remove teh jqclass:
    $(".jqclass").removeClass("jqclass");
    // Show the clicked photo:
    $("#"+photo).show();
    // Add the class and the zoom:
    $("#"+photo+" a").addClass("jqclass").jqzoom(options);
});
```

Comment: That is almost a spot on solution! Looking at the code it makes sense so thanks for making it understandable :) Onlt small thing is that on e all images after the first one, a second ghost zoom window shows with nothing in it, which look slike it is coming from having the (".jqclass").jqzoom(options) part called twice. When i take the first instance of it out then the blank zoom window disappears (though naturally the initial mainimage has no zoom until you swap images).

Comment: would there be some way of adding an onLoad command to the $(".jqclass").jqzoom(options); line? so that it is only run the very first time the page loads, and after that it would use the line from the click function..

Comment: ok, sorted it by naming the first image as jqclassorig. After that each thumbnail clicked calls jqclass so no repeated calass, no extra zoom box :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can clean the data from jQZoom:

```
$('.jqclass').removeData('jqzoom');
```

Because jQZoom saves the object data the following way:

```
$(el).data("jqzoom", obj);
```