# how can i unbind and rebind jqzoom

Tags: jquery

I've tried unbind and rebind jqzoom as shown below:

```
$('.jqzoom').unbind(); 

$('.jqzoom').jqzoom(options);
```

But nothing has happened. can any please help me how to do this?

Link : http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/

Comment: by using .unbind() you detach all event listeners on element but not the markup around it - if you're talking about this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305777/jqzoom-on-multiple-images has solution. :) might be what you want.

Comment: i have two different images. first time pic1 will show up and jqzoom is working fine, when i click the pic2 I'm changing the image attributes. The image is changing fine. But while zooming its showing the old image. How can i achive this without page refresh?

Answer (score 3):

try with

```
$.jqzoom.disable('.jqzoom')
```

and then

```
$.jqzoom.enable('.jqzoom')
```

as suggested inside the unpacked source code of `jquery.jqzoom-core.js` file, line `686`

Comment: I tried using $.jqzoom.disable('.jqzoom'), but I get this error: "TypeError: api.disable is not a function". Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

jQzoom does not have a way to do this but that does not matter, because you can always do that youself.

As with any other jQuery plugins the procedure is the same. 
All jquery plugins basically do the same thing. First they associate some data with the element. Lets say you have an image 
like this.

```
<a class="zoom_link"><img id="product_thumb_image" src="...link to image..." /></a>
```

and you also have  small images that you can click and change the big image. For example you have a big image of the product and some other small images of the same product from different angles.
 These are the small images.

```
<div id="small_images">

<a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="{gallery:'gal402', smallimage:'i1.jpg',  largeimage:'l1.jpg'}">
<img src="i1.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="{gallery:'gal402', smallimage:'i2.jpg',  largeimage:'l2.jpg'}">
<img src="i2.jpg" />
</a>


</div>
```

Since you call jqzoom like this

```
jQuery('.zoom_link').jqzoom({'preloadImages':true, zoomType: 'innerzoom' });
```

Then you will need to remove the data like this:

```
jQuery('.zoom_link').removeData('jqzoom')
```

But that's not enough because you still have event listeners bound to elements that you need to remove, otherwise you will not be able to re-enable jqzoom on the same element.
Here is how you do that 
***( unbind() without parameters removes all event listeners. )***

```
jQuery('.zoom_link').unbind();
/* These are the elements that jqzoom created */
jQuery('.zoomPad').unbind();
jQuery('.zoomPup').unbind();


/* For small images */
jQuery('#small_images').find('img').unbind();
jQuery('#small_images').find('a').unbind();
```

and finally we need to restore the original element contents that jqzoom altered by adding some other elements inside.

```
i = jQuery('.product_thumb_image').clone();
jQuery('.zoom_link').html( i.prop('outerHTML') );
```

What the above code does is cloning the image inside and replacing entire contents of the "**zoom_link**" element with the image like it was before we called jqzoom. 
After this you can call jqzoom again and it will work.

```
jQuery('.zoom_link').jqzoom({'preloadImages':true, zoomType: 'innerzoom' });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.jqzoom').removeData('jqzoom');
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you encountered some trouble using `removeData` or `disable` for disabling jqzoom, you can try this :

```
$('.jqzoom').data('jqzoom').disable();
```

In fact, under line 686 of jquery.jqzoom-core.js, you will find this two methods :

```
 disable: function (el) {
        var api = $(el).data('jqzoom');
        api.disable();
        return false;
    },
    enable: function (el) {
        var api = $(el).data('jqzoom');
        api.enable();
        return false;
    },
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I tried using:

$('.jqzoom').data('jqzoom').disable();

But I get the following error:

"TypeError: $(...).data(...).disable is not a function."

Any ideas why this happens? :(

Comment: What do you have if you log this : `console.log([$('.jqzoom'), $('.jqzoom').data('jqzoom')])`? Maybe you are using another version or you set another name to the jqZoom instance.